# Leaflet maerkercluster - Percentage instead of number of Children

Tags: javascript, leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

In many cases I need markercluster, it would be very interesting to show the rate of the total number of markers in the map (in form of %) instead of the number of the number of children of the cluster. So if you have 20 makers in that cluster and the total in the map is 200, I would like it to show 10% in that region of the map instead of 20.

Anyone has any idea of how to implement it?

thank you

---

Thank you for the solution, it is quite simple and works well, here is the code of the solution:

```
    $.getJSON(link, function(data) {
        var total_number = data.features.length; //Here I get the total number of markers
        var others = L.geoJson(data, {
            onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
                layer.bindPopup('Number: ' + feature.properties.Nr+' Residency:'+ feature.properties.Lives);
            },
         })
    var markers = L.markerClusterGroup({
        iconCreateFunction: function(cluster) {
            var markers = cluster.getAllChildMarkers();
            var n = ((markers.length/total_number)*100).toFixed(1);;
            return L.divIcon({ html: n+'%', className: 'mycluster', iconSize: L.point(40, 40) });
        },
    });
```

The CSS of the "myclusters" is the following:

```
    .mycluster {
        width: 150px;
        height: 15px;
        background-color: greenyellow;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 18px;
    }
```

Thanks you again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this puglin:
https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster

Example:

http://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.markercluster/example/marker-clustering-realworld.388.html

http://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.markercluster/example/marker-clustering-custom.html

To do a percentage, read this part:
https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster#customising-the-clustered-markers
`getChildCount()` or `getAllChildMarkers()` provide all the marks